# Сделать кнопку неактивной js

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать кнопку неактивной, если выбран 0 элемент списка, и активной, если другие элементы выбраны?

```
function showStreets(regionIndex,selectId) {
  if (regionIndex == 0)  {
    document.form_del.elements['submit'].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Так не работает :(

Comment: document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true

Comment: document.getElemntById("submit").setAttribute("disabled","");

Answer (score -1):

true должно быть в кавычках.

```
document.form_del.elements['submit'].disabled = 'true';
```

Comment: Это кто вам такое сказал, что нужно в кавычки? [читаем](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled) тут не верный селектор, а не в кавычки надо.